# How to find number of lines of a file?

Tags: c, file

for example:

```
file_ptr=fopen(“data_1.txt”, “r”);
```

how do i find number of lines in the file?

Comment: You should show us what you've already tried, besides the very first step of opening the file.

Answer (score 9):

You read every single character in the file and add up those that are newline characters.

You should look into `fgetc()` for reading a character and remember that it will return `EOF` at the end of the file and `\n` for a line-end character.

Then you just have to decide whether a final incomplete line (i.e., file has no newline at the end) is a line or not. I would say yes, myself.

Here's how I'd do it, in pseudo-code of course since this is homework:

```
open file
set line count to 0
read character from file
while character is not end-of-file:
    if character in newline:
        add 1 to line count
    read character from file
```

Extending that to handle a incomplete last line may not be necessary for this level of question. If it *is* (or you want to try for extra credits), you could look at:

```
open file
set line count to 0
set last character to end-of-file
read character from file
while character is not end-of-file:
    if character in newline:
        add 1 to line count
    set last character to character
    read character from file
if last character is not new-line:
    add 1 to line count
```

---

No guarantees that either of those will work since they're just off the top of my head, but I'd be surprised if they didn't (it wouldn't be the first or last surprise I've seen however - test it well).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHARBUFLEN 8

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int c, lineCount, cIdx = 0;
    char buf[CHARBUFLEN];
    FILE *outputPtr;

    outputPtr = popen("wc -l data_1.txt", "r");
    if (!outputPtr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Wrong filename or other error.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    do {
        c = getc(outputPtr);
        buf[cIdx++] = c;
    } while (c != ' ');
    buf[cIdx] = '\0';
    lineCount = atoi((const char *)buf);        

    if (pclose (outputPtr) != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unknown error.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf (stdout, "Line count: %d\n", lineCount);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: No one will need automatic plagiarism checking to determine that the student didn't write that one...  Your answer is going to influence all of my answers to homework questions!

Comment: The obvious (and correct) answer is to count newlines. I just thought it would be interesting to post an answer that might help the asker learn about `popen` (if s/he doesn't know about it already) for its generic potential to solve this and/or future homework problems.

Answer (score 1):

Is finding the line count the first step of some more complex operation?  If so, I suggest you find a way to operate on the file without knowing the number of lines in advance.

If your only purpose is to count the lines, then you must read them and... count!